# Create variable name in loop in Matlab from Python code

Tags: python, matlab, loops, variables, save

I have the following code in Python and I would like to implement something similar in MATLAB without using the eval syntax if possible.

The point is to create horizontal & vertical vectors from an irregular matrix and save them as a variable. In python this is straightforward but I am having problems with implementing this in MATLAB without using eval. Any ideas? Many thanks in advance!

e.g in python:

```
x,y = 3,5


matrix = np.zeros((x,y))

matrix_T = matrix.reshape(y,x)

array_names_y = ['name_y_%d' %i for i in xrange(y)] 

array_names_x = ['name_x_%d' %i for i in xrange(x)] 


for i in xrange(len(array_names_x)): 

     for name,row in zip(array_names_x,matrix):

            globals()[name]=row

for i in xrange(len(array_names_y)): 

     for name,column in zip(array_names_y,matrix_T):

           globals()[name]=column
```

The output is somthing like this:

columns:

```
name_y_0 = [ 0.  0.  0.]

name_y_1 = [ 0.  0.  0.]

name_y_2 = [ 0.  0.  0.]

name_y_3 = [ 0.  0.  0.]

name_y_4 = [ 0.  0.  0.]

rows:

name_x_0 = [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]

name_x_1 = [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]

name_x_2 = [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
```

I want to do this to later apply an analysis to each row/column vector.

Comment: can u explain a bit more about what you want ?

Comment: ***ARGH!!!***  Why?!? Why would you ever want to do that? Dynamically creating variables is **never** the right thing to do. My suggestion is: change your python code to *not* mess with `globals()` and then the code will map almost 1-to-1 to MATLAB (thus solving also the problem you asked). Read [How do I make a series of variables A1, A2, A3, ... A10?](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/143-how-do-i-make-a-series-of-variables-a1-a2-a3-a10)

Comment: Can't you rather use a cell array? But if you do want to do this, then why not use `eval`? It's a terrible idea as Bakuriu has mentioned, but if you are insisting on doing it then using `eval` is the "correct" approach. But like I said, rather use cell arrays, or structs

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sturct with dynamic names

```
for ii = 1:size(matrix,1)
    nm = sprintf('name_x_%d',ii-1);
    st.(nm) = matrix(ii,:);
end
for ii = 1:size(matrix,2)
    nm = sprintf('name_y_%d',ii-1);
    st.(nm) = matrix(:,ii).';
end
```

starting with

```
>> matrix = rand(3,5);
```

You end up with

```
>> st

st = 

name_x_0: [0.7268 0.3005 0.5994 0.4717 0.0194]
name_x_1: [0.7780 0.3819 0.8218 0.4820 0.3969]
name_x_2: [0.2287 0.6207 0.4578 0.5712 0.2943]
name_y_0: [0.7268 0.7780 0.2287]
name_y_1: [0.3005 0.3819 0.6207]
name_y_2: [0.5994 0.8218 0.4578]
name_y_3: [0.4717 0.4820 0.5712]
name_y_4: [0.0194 0.3969 0.2943]
```

But, please, *please*, **please**, ***PLEASE*** listen to [Bakuriu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622216/create-variable-name-in-loop-in-matlab-from-python-code/25622723#comment40029143_25622216).

Comment: Voting down, because I don't think the discouragement at the bottom is enough. To me, this is not useful. The entire approach should be strongly discouraged.

Comment: @Schorsch: But isn't a `struct` like this more akin to the cell array approach even though it retains more meaningful names rather than just indices? The MathWorks link from @Bakuriu above suggests a similar approach. Or is it that dynamic `struct` names are effectively the same as using `eval`?

Comment: @horchler Personal preference, here (and a dislike of anonymous down-votes for answers). I think something like `st.name{1,1}.x` or `st.name{1,1}.y` is cleaner. In addition, using indexing that starts at `0` (even just in names) could lead to confusion later, because Matlab does not use a `0`-index.

Comment: @Schorsch I understand your concern regarding the dynamic field names. However, regarding the 0-based indexing - I was just following the OP requirements.